# Remove lines from CSV file

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a .CSV file (file1) that looks like

```
Initials,Size excl. Backup/Pst,Number of warnings
USER1,100,1
USER10,1000,1
USER12,1100,1
USER13,1200,1
```

I have another .CSV file (file2) that looks like

```
Initials,Size excl. Backup/Pst
USER1,100
USER4,400
USER10,1000
USER11,1100
```

I'm trying to remove the lines from file1, where the username is not in file2.
So my output should be: (USER12 and USER13 is removed from the file, since they are not in file2)

```
Initials,Size excl. Backup/Pst,Number of warnings
USER1,100,1
USER10,1000,1
```

Here's what I have

```
$ArrayDB1   = $file1 | Import-Csv | Select-Object Initials
$ArrayUSERS = $file2 | Import-Csv | Select-Object Initials
$ArrayDiff  = Compare-Object ($ArrayDB1) ($ArrayUSERS1) -Property Initials |
              Where-Object { $_.SideIndicator -eq '<=' } |
              Select-Object Initials
```

This gives me (in `$ArrayDiff`):

```
Initials
--------
USER12
USER13
```

So far so good. But when I try to remove it from file1 using the below

```
Select-String $file1 -Pattern $ArrayDiff -NotMatch |
  select -Expand line |
  Out-File "file3.log"
```

The file3 just gives me whats in file1. Nothing is removed:

```
Initials,Size excl. Backup/Pst,Number of warnings
USER1,100,1
USER10,1000,1
USER12,1100,1
USER13,1200,1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$userlist = Import-Csv $file2 | % { $_.Initials }

Import-Csv $file1 | ? { $userlist -contains $_.Initials } | Export-Csv $file3
```

The first line creates an array from the `Initials` column of the 2<sup>nd</sup> CSV. With that array you can use the `-contains` operator for selecting just those records from the 1<sup>st</sup> CSV that have a matching `Initials` value.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I changed the "export-csv $file3" to: "convertto-csv -NoTypeInformation | % { $_ -replace '"', ""} | out-file file3" to get the output as I wanted it.